# React final form, parse float input?

Tags: react-final-form

How to make float input in react final form? I do like this:

```
parse={value =>{!parseFloat(value) || !Number(value) || value.endsWith(".") ? value : parseFloat(value);}}
```

But I can type letters and when I put `1.` it`s string, but I need float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice, in my experience, is to leave it as a string in your form values and

- use client-side validation to confirm that it's a valid Number
- convert to a Number on submit